# Switching between two Eval values on the asp.net front end page

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, ado.net

Developers, I am in need of providing different

```
<%# Eval("variable") %>
```

For my Grid.   I have requirements that require me to either show StagingDB Data or ProdDB Data per Eval

Pseudocode

```
<%# If Eval("isDraft) ? Eval("tbl_staging_value") : Eval("tbl_value") %>
```

Stackoverflowers... You are my only hope...  Thanks.   Working on Sunday...

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[?: operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)**.

```
<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("isDraft")) ? Eval("tbl_staging_value"): 
    Eval("tbl_value") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

By creating a new property on your data source

```
 public string tbl_val
 {
     get
     {
         return isDraft ? tbl_staging_value : tbl_value;
     }
 }
```

you can simplify the data binding

```
<%# Eval("tbl_val") %>
```